# Symfony console "ask" won't accept empty values

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

I am playing with the symfony console package where I am making it ask for a value when the command is executed, aka in `public function execute(...)`.

When trying to ask the user for something, I have figured it is two different ways to do it if you're not making a own custom style. a) Using the Question helper, b) using the predefined Styles, hereby `SymfonyStyle`
I started off using the `SymfonyStyle` running a simple `ask("question here")` and it kept give me errors if I did not give it a value. If I used the helper instead, creating the question directly, then it would allow me to give it an empty value.

Here is some examples:

```
# SomeCommand.php
namespace What\A\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

// ...
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // ...

    // With the helper, which allows empty answer
    $helper = $this->getHelper('question');
    $q = new Question('Question here');

    dump($helper->ask($input, $output, $q));
    // Output:
    // Question here
    // null


    // With SymfonyStyle which DOES NOT allow empty answer
    $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
    dump($io->ask("Question here"));
    // Output:
    // Question here:
    // [ERROR] A value is required.
}
```

Looking into the file of `SymfonyStyle`, it looks like it doesn't do much different with the validation at all, as the class says, it's just styling.
So is there something I am missing which is the difference between these two? Is it possible to achieve to make `SymfonyStyle` to accept empty answers at all?

Comment: yes, with the SymfonyStyle the input seems mandatory instead of using a default value. Check the SymfonyQuestionHelper class

Comment: Aah, didnt notice it didnt directly used the Question class, thanks for guiding me to it. I found that `SymfonyQuestionHelper` required a value to be valid. Now I know how to proceed to allow it to be empty, but also keep the same style without breaking DRY :) Thanks, @Matteo!

Comment: Hi @Morten you are welcome!

Comment: Have to withdraw my statement about using `SymfonyStyle` without breaking DRY... All the properties and some methods are given `private` instead of `protected`, so I can't "steal" it without breaking the DRY principle..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in this case:
(this is an extract of a class where `$this->io= new SymfonyStyle($input, $output)`).

Its pretty unlikely in my use case that the placeholder will be in the user input.

```
public function askAllowEmpty($question, $default)
    {
        $placeholder = \uniqid("placeholder");
        $field = $this->io->ask($question, $default, function($string) use ($placeholder) {
               return (null == $string)? $placeholder : $string;
        });
        return str_replace($placeholder, null, $field);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
$question = new Question(
    "Please insert a value",
    false
);

$userInput = $io->askQuestion($question);


$finalValue = $userInput ? $userInput : null;
```

the last line is needed to actually make `$finalValue` as `null` (instead of `false`) when the user does not insert anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple as long as you understand that a question can get a false response but not a null response. Using SymfonyStyle, this can be done in a single line:

```
$answer = $this->io->ask("Ask a question?", false) ?: null);
```

Of course, this makes the assumption that you would not require a false response.